# c3.js | Changing the x-axis tick to year format

Tags: javascript, jquery, c3.js

I am trying to change the date format to year when the user selects last 7 years but I am having issues. The problem is that all x axis ticks say "01-01" (I generated the chart in %d-%m format) when I really want it to display the year instead.

```
    if (this.value === "year") {
            console.log("clicked");
            chart.load({
                x: 'x',
                columns: [yearData,
                    membersGender2[0],
                    membersGender2[1],
                    membersGenderTotal2
                ],
                types: {
                    Male: 'area-spline',
                    Female: 'area-spline',
                    Total: 'line'
                }
            });
            chart.x([yearData[1], yearData[2], yearData[3], yearData[4], yearData[5], yearData[6], yearData[7]]);
            console.log("years ==>", yearData);
}
```

Comment: I think what you're asking is how to display the year instead of months on the axes, but I'm not sure. Can you clarify your question further?

Comment: I have if statement that will check what is selected (this month data, this year data), and i couldn't get it to work for year. i want to change the x axis from format: '%m-%d' to year only

Comment: Ok. I changed the question to clarify what you're asking.